# React JS- Is React re-render the web page after form submitting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am so new in React JS. I am not maintaining a code that is written by someone else. My question may be too basic, sorry for this.

There is a form in the page. Is page is re-rendered after clicking the Submit button ? In my onSubmit method, there is not a code piece that re-render the web page. For example, after submitting the form, I want to set a label "Register is successful or not". Also if there is a validation error in the form, I want to colorize the input fields.

Actually I do not know when react re-renders page and which part of the page it renders ? How can I force React to re-render somewhere in the page ?

This is my `onSubmit` method;

```
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.setState({
    loading: true,
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
    });
  }, 1000);

  const data = this.constructFormData();

  fetch('/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
  })
    .then(p => {
    if (p.status === 200) {
      return p.json();
    }

    throw '500';
  })
    .catch(err => {
    this.setState({
      error: true,
    });
  });
}
```

And below is my form definition ;

```
<form
    id="register-form"
    method="POST"
    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
    autoComplete="off"
>
```

Comment: Can I recommend you to put 
`this.setState({
      loading: false,
 });`

in the promise `.then(p => {
    if (p.status === 200) {
      return p.json();
    }

    throw '500';
  })`

That will stop the loading as soon as you get the response which is much better than fixed 1 second with setTimeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

whenever you call `setState()`, form re-renders.
You can learn about setState in [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).
You can force re-render using `forceUpdate()`, but it is not advisable. Alternatively, you can do `this.setState(this.state)`

Comment: Is React renders as soon as the state was changed ? In my case, I can set a state value (for example a label text) before submitting form.Will it be rendered immediately ?

Comment: SetState is asynchronous. The function that is executing will complete it's execution first, then only it will re-render.

Answer (score 4):

> Actually I do not know when react re-renders page and which part of the page it renders ?

It renders the page once, then  it only rerenders a component where the state was changed using setState. If that rerender adds new elements, they get rendered too.

> How can I force React to re-render somewhere in the page

Move the data that changes into the state and call `setState` if it changes.

Comment: do you mean the all page from the component ? For example I have a web page and my class definiton starts with class App extends Component { ...     I have 4 textbox in this page. Can I render only one textbox in this page ?

Comment: @mhendek then add a state to App that stores which textbox to show, then inside `render()` only return the textbox the state indicates